# Positioning div without overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a validation control elements in ASP.NET which they needs to be inside form tag in order to work, that's why I'm doing silly things with positioning div which includes validation controls but I can't get it to work. Please check my two images:

Here is my current layout. Gray div is actually div whre validation controls are. Because as you see this site has plenty of space so I want to position gray div on the left side, just like you will see in second image.
[image]

[image]

I've already positioned like shows upper image (with properties: top, left, position absolute), but if I resize browser window, gray div will overlay centered div ( will stay on the same spot ). Check following image to see what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very easy answer! Give your `body` a `min-width`.

```
body {
    min-width: 1000px;
}
```

You will have to find out what the brown div and gray div equal plus a little room to give space between them.

If you want it to happen only on a certain page then use this java script if statement.

```
if(document.location.href === 'pageURL.com') {
    $('body').css('min-width', '1500px');
}
```

to find page URL go into a web console and type in `document.location.href` and it will give you the exact url.

Comment: Glad I could aid a helping hand, best of luck to you mate.